# DbUtils QueryRunner with fields of the same name

Tags: java, mysql

I swear I've done this before and it's worked fine, but it seems that with the query I have (below) I can't map two columns of the same name (in this case 'email') even when using "as" in my query.  I've also tried without the "as" - just having 'u.email assessorEmail' and that query works as well, but with the same problem, the field just doesn't appear in my results when I debug.

```
getQueryRunner().query("SELECT u.email AS assessorEmail, f.formid, f.firstName, f.surname, f.email, f.valid, f.invalidreason FROM users AS u RIGHT JOIN userforms AS uf ON u.id=uf.user LEFT JOIN forms AS f ON uf.form=f.formid WHERE u.role=? AND f.submitted=1 AND f.valid=0 ORDER BY u.email", new MapListHandler(), Role.ASSESSOR);
```

MySql result:

```
assessorEmail           formid  firstName   surname email           valid   invalidreason
assessor@test.com       547     John        Doe     user@test.com   0
```

Eclipse->inspect variable:

```
[{valid=false, invalidreason=, email=user@test.com, surname=Doe, firstName=John, formid=547}]
```

If I remove f.email from the query, the u.email appears successfully as 'email' (still not assessorEmail).

Is this a DbUtils thing? A QueryRunner thing? Even a MySql Java connector thing? I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious here...

Comment: Probably a MySQL driver problem. But there have been fixes (and maybe regressions) in this area in DbUtils as well (mostly to work around driver quirks I think). Can you try different versions of the modules?

Comment: I've just tried updating everything to the latest - DBUtils, Mysql Connector, and MySQL itself, but unfortunately that didn't do the trick.  Might try some older combinations later if I can find one I know used to work in some other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little more digging I found a bug listing for this issue http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=32504.  Seems to be an issue with the connector.

Adding "useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true" as a parameter to the JDBC URL did the trick.